# How to generate random values for a boolean array?

Tags: java

I want to set true or false values for boolean array randomly. How to generate those values randomly for an android application?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`java.util.Random` has a method called `nextBoolean()` you could use to populate the array.

```
// assumes a java.util.Random called random
boolean[] randomBools(int len) {
    boolean[] arr = new boolean[len];
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        arr[i] = random.nextBoolean();
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Random random = new Random(); //java.util.Random
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = random.nextBoolean();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Boolean[] values;
Random rand = new Random(SEED);

values = new Boolean[ARR_SIZE];

for(int i = 0; i<ARR_SIZE; i++)
{
  values[i] = rand.nextBoolean();
}
```

Something like this should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean[] arr = new boolean[10];
Random r = new Random();

for(int i=0 ; i<arr.length ; i++){

    arr[i] = r.nextBoolean();

 }
```